# How is dividing basically "subtracting several times"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I keep hearing that dividing is basically "subtracting by a number several times" but I don't see how. ie multiplying 5 5 times:
$$5+5+5+5+5 = 25 = 5\times5$$

But if you want to divide 25 by 5 you can't subtract 5 five times or you get zero, not 5.

Comment: I don't know who told you this, but it is not.

Comment: It's the number of times you need to subtract, in order to get zero.

Comment: You count how many times you can subtract without getting a negative number result

Comment: I suggest getting past the "multiplication is repeated addition" and "dividing is number of groups needed of size __" style thinking.  It is only helpful in building intuition for the very restrictive cases of working in positive integers and for division when division doesn't result in a remainder.  If you don't grow past it, you will be confused by $2.5\times (-3.3)$ and by $\frac{5}{2}$

Comment: You count the number of times you subtract.  $79\div 13$ .  $79-13=66$ ONE  $66-13=53$  TWO  $53-13 = 40$ THREE $40-13=27$ FOUR $27-13=14$ FIVE and $14-13=1$ SIX.  So $79\div 13 = 6$ and $1$ remainder.

Comment: @JMoravitz no you won't, half of -3.3 is -1.65 . so 2.5 multiplied by $(-3.3) = (-3.3)+(-3.3)+(-1.65) = (-6.6)+(-1.65)=(-8.25)$  it's only multiplying irrational numbers that will confuse them.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee you underestimate the extent to which people can get confused over what might seem routine to others.  Regardless, you missed the point of my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for addition, you started off with $0$. When you added $5$ to the number $0$ five times, you attained $25$. Division is the inverse process. It asks how many times one must subtract $5$ to come back to $0$.

Comment: I would personally rather say that division asks "How many 5s must you add to get to 25?" It's ultimately the same thing, but it makes the relationship between multiplication and division somewhat more explicit.

Comment: However I wanted to highlight why multiplication is explained as repeated addition and division as repeated subtraction.

Comment: I agree that this is probably the answer sought. But it is not, in my opinion, not the "right" way to formulate division in this context. This is a matter of personal aesthetic sense more than anything else, thoguh.

Comment: True. I also wanted to convey how division is the inverse of multiplication as addition and subtraction are also inverse functions of each other.

Answer (score 2):

I think the fact that 25 is a perfect square is confusing you because the divisor and quotient are the same when divided by 5. If you take the number 30 and subtract the number “5” 6 times, you get 0. Thus, 30/5 = 6.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply $5$ by $5$ using addition:

$$\begin{align*}
&0+5=5\qquad\text{count }1\\
&5+5=10\qquad\text{count }2\\
&10+5=15\qquad\text{count }3\\
&15+5=20\qquad\text{count }4\\
&20+5=25\qquad\;\text{ count }5\;
\end{align*}$$
Here, the number $5$ has been repeatedly added $5$ times. We can say that the number $5$ has been added $5$ times from $0$. So, we can write this addition as $5 \times 5 = 25$.

To divide $25$ by $5$ using subtraction:

$$\begin{align*}
&25-5=20\qquad\text{count }1\\
&20-5=15\qquad\text{count }2\\
&15-5=10\qquad\text{count }3\\
&10-5=5\qquad\text{count }4\\
&5-5=0\qquad\;\text{ count }5\;
\end{align*}$$

Here, the number $5$ has been repeatedly subtracted $5$ times. We can say that the number $5$ has been subtracted $5$ times from $25$. So, we can write this subtraction as $25 \div 5 = 5$.

Answer (score 1):

I remember from years ago a question about the Euclidean algorithm for the greatest common divisor (GCD). Someone else wrote something to the effect that the Euclidean algorithm does not actually use division.

That might be true from a philosophical point of view, though in practice you'll probably want to implement it with division.

For example, calculate $\gcd(5, 28)$. You already know the answer is 1, but please play along for a minute. Dividing, we find that $$\frac{28}{5} = 5.6.$$ But for the Euclidean algorithm we care more about the remainder, so $$\frac{28}{5} - \left\lfloor \frac{28}{5} \right\rfloor = 3,$$ and $0.6 \times 5 = 3,$ so this checks out.

But we can also get there by repeated subtraction: $28 - 5 = 23$, $23 - 5 = 18$, $18 - 5 = 13$, $13 - 5 = 8$ and $8 - 5 = 3$. I'd hate to have to do this for $\gcd(7028, 5)$.

So $28 = 5m_1 + 3$ (we don't really care what $m_1$ is), and then $5 = 3m_2 + 2$, and $3 = 2m_3 + 1$ and there's our answer.

Now, the analogy doesn't quite hold up when 0 is involved. For example, what's $\gcd(0, 43)$? Don't you try to divide 43 by 0, your calculator will melt... just kidding. But... $43 - 0 = 43$... tells us nothing, it does not move the algorithm along.

The point is that division is "basically" repeated subtraction, but it is not exactly that.